# Two forms and h:messages, decide what messages to display

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have two h:forms and single h:messages in one of them. How can I display validation errors from that form only? I want to ignore all messages from other form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're already on JSF2, consider replacing synchronous requests by asynchronous requests by bringing in `<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form">` at the necessary places.

E.g.

```
<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    <h:inputText required="true" />
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="submit">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>

<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    <h:inputText required="true" />
    ...
    <h:commandButton value="submit">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

This way only the content of the current `<h:form>` will be re-rendered upon submit. Additional benefit is faster feedback and improved user experience due to use of ajax.

If that's not an option for some reason, your best bet is to use the `rendered` attribute to conditionally show the `<h:messages>` component depending on the button invoked (whose name=value pair (the name is the client ID) would be present in the request parameter map then). For example,

```
<h:form>
    <h:messages rendered="#{not empty param[button1.clientId]}" />
    <h:inputText required="true" />
    ...
    <h:commandButton binding="#{button1}" value="submit" />
</h:form>

<h:form>
    <h:messages rendered="#{not empty param[button2.clientId]}" />
    <h:inputText required="true" />
    ...
    <h:commandButton binding="#{button2}" value="submit" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified your second solution to `<h:commandButton id="sendButton"/> <h:messages rendered="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(param,'sendButton')}"/>`